# Can I use the logo of the R statistical package on my webpage?

Tags: trademark, logos

I am a statistical programmer. As a SAS certified programmer, I can put the SAS logo on my website. I would like to also display the R logo, because many clients want programming in R. Does anyone know where I can find licensing terms and conditions to use the R logo?

The R website is here: http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/

I have checked FAQs, Stack Overflow etc. The R mailing lists are dedicated to programming questions and bug reports, not licensing questions.

Comment: You are using the wrong website. Take a look at https://www.r-project.org/Licenses/ and may someone have mercy on you trying to sort *that* one out ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From looking at the source code, most of R itself (vs the various packages) is licensed under one or other GPL variant. Certainly the logo file does not seem to have a specific license associated with it.

This question has actually been addressed in one of the [R mail lists](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-January/150728.html)

> Jan Wijffels wrote:
>
> > Hi,
> >
> > I was wondering if there are any guidelines for the use of the R logo on websites which are for commercial use? Similar to
> >     http://www.python.org/community/logos/ for Python and to
> >     http://www.postgresql.org/community/propaganda for PostgreSQL perhaps?
> >
> > It has been discussed internally, but as far as I remember no official document ever transpired. The general sentiment (still
> >     according to my memory) was that usage is OK as long as it doesn't
> >     imply endorsement by R Core or the R Foundation, or any other
> >     commingling with commercial products.
>
> R and the "chocolate pretzel" logo are not registered as trademarks,
>   but even if they were, then "nominative usage" (as described in the
>   PSF Trademark Use Policy) should not be problematic.  In cases of
>   doubt, ask!
>
> --     O__  ---- Peter Dalgaard             Øster Farimagsgade 5, Entr.B   c/ /'_ --- Dept. of Biostatistics     PO Box 2099, 1014 Cph.
>   K  (*) (*) -- University of Copenhagen   Denmark          Ph:  (+45)
>   35327918 ~~~~~~~~~~ - (p.dalgaard at biostat.ku.dk)
>   FAX: (+45) 35327907

The implication is that you are OK as long as you  are not implying any certification or endorsement by the project. However, a quick emal to one of the maintainers can probably clear it up for you.

UPDATE:

Some googling found this README at [this site](https://developer.r-project.org/Logo/):

> This directory contains the R Logo in several resolutions.
>
> Rlogo-x.png has been used since approx 2000 for most purposes.  Number
>   5 is currently used for web pages. The PNG versions have a transparent
>   background, the JPEG has a white background. These versions can be
>   distributed under the GPL.
>
> Rlogo.svg has been created by Tobias Wolf  in
>   October 2010, Rlogo.pdf is just a PDF created off the SVG using
>   inkscape. Both can be distributed under the Creative Commons
>   Attribution ShareAlike license, see http://creativecommons.org/.

Now the question you need to think  about is whether you copy the logo file to your server (and what effect that has on the entire web site) or link to it

Comment: Nice mess, that one ;-)